# How to turn a heading into a list item in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

When working on the structure of a document, often I find myself wanting to turn a list of items into a set of headings, or a set of headings into a list.  I haven't found a way to do this easily other than by hand-editing or recording a macro.

How do you do it? Is there a function to do this kind of operations, e.g. demote a heading to a list item?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In org-mode, it is easy enough to turn a heading into an item. There is a command called `org-toggle-item` which can do that, and it is bound with `C-c -`.

Also, you can also use `org-toggle-heading` to turn an item to a heading, which is bound with `C-c *`.

Comment: This happened to me by chance several times, but I never could figure out what key did I press to achieve this effect! :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote: "C-c *" is bound to org-ctrl-c-star at least today. But this function decides by context what to do. It either calls org-table-recalculate or org-toggle-heading.

Comment: The tricky thing is that both headings and list items can start with `*`. So supposedly, if there are no leading spaces before `*`, it is a heading. But then people seem to make it not display all the asterisks for headings, and the distinction probably gets even more blurry.